# Typescript - Is it possible to get a namespace from a class with the same name?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```
class Common {}
namespace Common {
  export class Thing {}
}

const instance = new Common();
```

Is it possible to somehow get the type of Thing from instance?

Edit:
For more context, I'm not writing the class and namespace definitions, they're being generated by protobuf.js and I'm trying to get a type relative to an instance. Is this possible?

Comment: TypeScript doesn't strongly type the `constructor` property of constructed objects, see [microsoft/TypeScript#3841](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841), so it's not possible to say `typeof instance.constructor.Thing` without declaring a more strongly-typed `constructor` property [yourself](https://tsplay.dev/4WyE2W).  I don't really understand what you're trying to do, though, so I can't say if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: @PatrickWang yon you give a simple example of what you after? Perhaps some sample code of something importing this file and then using it? Even if the sample itself now fails it might give some more context.